# Use math symbols to produce 6

Tags: calculation-puzzle

How can we get (6) from these numbers?

$2$  $2$  $2 = 6$

$3$  $3$  $3 = 6$

$4$  $4$  $4 = 6$

$5$  $5$  $5 = 6$

$6$  $6$  $6 = 6$

$7$  $7$  $7 = 6$

$8$  $8$  $8 = 6$

$9$  $9$  $9 = 6$

$12$ $12$ $12 = 6$

$15$ $15$ $15 = 6$

Comment: Please specify — which operations can we use? Can we use the square root function $\sqrt{n}$ ? Can we use the floor/ceiling functions to round (like I have in my answer)?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry it's worth a discussion whether this is a dupelicate. In a question like this, one person might ask for 0 through 9, and then another person might ask for 0 through 15. **Is the whole question a duplicate if part of the question is a duplicate?**

Comment: if you want you could carry the concept on indefinitely, but the principle is the same as in the duplicate. @Hugh

Comment: @benasfan is my answer better now?

Comment: @Hugh much much better for 12, still that for 15 doesn't require complex work. Believe me it is as easy as the whole question is. An answer with a simple calc and a pencil would be more than sufficient like that of 12.

Comment: @benasfan ok, quick question: by "simple operations" do you mean $x + y$, $x - y$, $x \times y$, $x \div y$, $\sqrt{x}$, $x^y$ and $x!$? Also, are the rest of my answers (2 through to 9, and 12) good?

Comment: @Hugh (2 through to 9, and12) yes they are good , you can use simple operation like those, yes, why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some searches on Google and found:

> (*Click on equation for WolframAlpha link*)
> 2. [$2 + 2 + 2 = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20%2B%202%20%2B%202) 
> 3. [$3 \times 3 - 3 = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%20*%203%20-%203) 
> 4. [$\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4} = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(4)%20%2B%20sqrt(4)%20%2B%20sqrt(4)) 
> 5. [$5 + \frac{5}{5} = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%20%2B%205%2F5)
> 6. [$6×\frac{6}{6} = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%20*%206%2F6)
> 7. [$7 - \frac{7}{7} = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%20-%207%2F7)
> 8. [$8 - \sqrt{\sqrt{8 + 8}} = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8%20-%20sqrt(sqrt(8%20%2B%208)))
> 9. [$\sqrt{9 \times 9} - \sqrt{9} = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(9*9)%20-%20sqrt(9))
> 12. [$\sqrt{12 + 12 + 12} = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(12%20%2B%2012%20%2B%2012)) or [$12 \log_{12} {\sqrt{12}}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(log%20base%2012%20of%20(sqrt(12)))%20*%2012) where $\log_xy$ is the base $x$ [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).
> 15. [$\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{15 \times 15}}\rfloor + \lfloor\sqrt{15}\rfloor = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(sqrt(sqrt(15*15)))%20%2B%20floor(sqrt(15))) where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the [mathematical floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), which "takes as input a real number and gives as output the greatest integer less than or equal to the input number" or [$\pi(15 + \frac{15}{15}) = 6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primes%20less%20than%20(15%20%2B%20(15%2F15))) where $\pi(x)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) or [$\Gamma(\sqrt{15 + \frac{15}{15}})$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma(sqrt(15%20%2B%2015%2F15))) where $\Gamma(x)$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) which for positive integers is equal to $\Gamma(n) = (n - 1)!$

And here are a few more that aren't required in the original post:

> 1. $(1 + 1 + 1)! = 6$ 
> 10. $\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{10 \times 10}} \rfloor + \sqrt{\lfloor\sqrt{10}\rfloor} = 6$ 
> 11. $\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{11 \times 11}} \rfloor + \sqrt{\lfloor\sqrt{11}\rfloor} = 6$ 
> 13. $\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{13 \times 13}} \rfloor + \sqrt{\lfloor\sqrt{13}\rfloor} = 6$ 
> 14. $\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{14 \times 14}} \rfloor + \sqrt{\lfloor\sqrt{14}\rfloor} = 6$ 
> 16. $\sqrt{16} + \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{16 * 16}}} = 6$

Comment: Finish it, don't google it.

Comment: Why is googling not allowed? If it is, please direct me to the part of the rules page where it says this. You asked for it!

Comment: hhhhh, if google is allowed, then what value to it ? The good thing is that google can't answer the last two rows.

Comment: @benasfan yes, I see that google isn't the best tool for finding these sorts of things - most only do 0 to 9. But, sometimes searching pays off. I found 12 online and then that gave me the insight to do 15.

Comment: I am afraid the pattern doesn't work right. As for 10 it gives 6.325,  for 11 you get 6.633 and for 15 we get 7.746 check it yourself. As a rule, we can't have the same answer from different numbers applying the same pattern.

Comment: @benasfan unfortunately, as this is online, I could write an answer and say I did not google it, and you will not be able to prove that I am lying unless you have full access to my doings on the internet. Even if I was *not* lying, you would not be able to prove that I was telling the truth, either. It is honest of **Hugh** to include that he carried out a quick search on Google :\

Comment: @user477343 Yes it is. I liked when Mr. Hugh said that. Although I woudn't mention google at all unless he said so first.

Comment: @benasfan no, it does not. $\lfloor x \rfloor$ indicates the floor function, which "_takes as input a real number and gives as output the greatest integer less than or equal to the real number_". So, for 15 we have: $\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{15 \times 15}}\rfloor + \lfloor\sqrt{15}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{15}\rfloor + \lfloor\sqrt{15}\rfloor = \lfloor 3.87 \rfloor + \lfloor 3.87 \rfloor = 3 + 3 = 6$. Basically, it rounds down to the nearest whole number... which is why some consider it "cheaty" in these questions bcz. 6 is really just 5.0001 to 6.9999 and one can use floor/ceiling from there.

Comment: @Hugh When I answered for 15, I used a simple equation. The result was amazing, such that the output was 5,999999355.

Comment: @benasfan I see, but the floor function isn't that complicated... it results in 6: [wolframalpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(sqrt(sqrt(15+*+15)))+%2B+floor(sqrt(15)))

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer:

After looking at [@Hugh's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71665/use-math-symbols-to-produce-6/71666#71666), particularly the comments below it, I wanted to try and solve a few parts of the puzzle without using the internet. It is up to you whether or not you believe me.

The following is all I have found thus far.

> 2. $$2^2+2=6$$

> 3. $$3!+3-3=6\tag*{$\big(n!=1\times 2\times \cdots \times n\big)$}$$

> 4. $$4+4-\sqrt{4} = 6$$

> 5. $$\pi(5+5+5)=6\tag*{$\big(\pi(x) =$ PCF$\big)$}$$ <sub>See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).</sub>

> 6. $$6^{6\,\div\, 6} = 6$$

> 7. $$\big\lceil \sqrt7+\sqrt{7+\sqrt7}\big\rceil=6$$ I could substitute $7$ with $8$ or $9$ and change the ceilng function $\lceil\ldots\rceil$ to the floor $\lfloor\ldots\rfloor$ instead and then have solutions regarding $8$ and $9$... but that would ruin some fun, I suppose.

> 8. $$\bigg\lfloor\frac{8+\sqrt{8}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{8}}}\bigg\rfloor=6$$ Also works for $9$ and if I change the ceiling function to the floor, it works for $6$ and $7$.

> $$\sqrt{9}!\times 9\div 9 = 6$$ I would have instead added $9$ and then subtracted $9$ as opposed to multiplying and dividing, but I already did that with regards to $3$ and wanted to make this that little extra different.

> 10. $$\big\lfloor\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{10}\big\rfloor_{10}=6\tag*{$\big(n_{10}=n\big)$}$$

Comment: Good for you for not googling, my first instinct in a question like this is to google, especially because this type of question is so standard. I assume that _someone_, _somewhere_ on this planet has already solved a problem like this, they just need to be found.

Comment: I do believe you. No need to prove it's the truth or not.

Comment: @Hugh hahah, I know, right? That's what I think about when I see that the Twin Prime Conjecture *still* remains unproven... unless someone out there in the world has the proof but just hasn't submitted it or something, hahah :P

Comment: @user477343 this whole "Riemann hypothesis" thing? _somebody_ must know the answer! lol

Comment: @user477343 Now do the math for 12 and 15 . U almost done.

Comment: @benasfan sorry about that. I had to quickly leave. I am busy on Saturdays, and could only edit just now. I will continue back on :P